# Change specific buttons background onPress (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to build a simple quiz. I would like to change the background of a button to green if it's correct and to red if it's incorrect onPress. My questions is how do I select only ONE of the buttons? Currently I can only get all of the buttons to turn colour.

```
export default class TestScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.qno = 0
        this.score = 0

        const jdata = jsonData.quiz.quiz1
        arrnew = Object.keys(jdata).map( function(k) { return jdata[k] });
        this.state = {
          question : arrnew[this.qno].question,
          options : arrnew[this.qno].options,
          correctoption : arrnew[this.qno].correctoption,
          countCheck : 0,
          back_colour: 'gray',
          answered: false,
        }
    }
    change_colour(ans) {
        if(this.state.answered == false){
          if(ans == this.state.correctoption){
            Alert.alert('Correct!');
            this.setState({ back_colour: 'green'})
          }
          else {
            Alert.alert('Wrong!');
            this.setState({ back_colour: 'red'})
          }
          this.setState({ answered: true })
        }
        else {
          // Do nothing
        }
    }
    render() {
        let _this = this
        const currentOptions = this.state.options
        const options = Object.keys(currentOptions).map( function(k) {
          return (  <View key={k} style={{margin:10}}>

            <Button color={_this.state.back_colour} onPress={() => _this.change_colour(k)} title={currentOptions[k]} />

          </View>)
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
yeah its great and easy with react . You can use ids for this purpose.
```

example ..

```
validateUser = id => {
  const newItems = items.map(item => {
  if(item.id === id ) {
      then check anwer here 
      and trun status true or false ..
}
})
}

items.map(item function() {
  <Button color={item.status ? 'red' : 'black' } onPress={() => 
       this.validateAnswer(item.id)}>
  })
```

and your item object in your array should be like this ..

```
{
 id: '0',
 status: true/false  
}
```

i think this will help .